# closed as dupe search rank

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't questions closed as dupe's show up lower on the search rank than the questions they are duplicates of? For eample, search for Free Books, the second result is 
[Are there any free C# e-books available online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427584/are-there-any-free-c-sharp-e-books-available-online) which was closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391523/what-are-some-good-free-programming-books which was merged with 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books, which shows up on fourth position in the list.

I mean they do both show up, but what is the value of listing the dupe in the search results in the first place?

Comment: This is also why we have downvotes

Comment: <strike>Yay more questions to close.</strike> Locked...wouldn't you know it.

Answer (score 2):

### Search algorithms are complex

Search is more complex than just sorting by rank or votes, search for `freely books` to get an idea.

If I search for `down`, I don't want `down-votes` to have preference over `down` in my results. This is exactly the behavior you see here, a result that has `free` gets preference over `freely`.

### Downvotes influence the results

As random [stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109829/closed-as-dupe-search-rank#comment-283936)

> This is also why we have downvotes

you can influence this by downvoting the question, take for example a look on the latest page of the search results and you will see that a lot of downvoted questions get to be there.

### Why your idea is bad

Let's say a dupe of your question is called

> Can we have less duplicated questions show up in the search?

then searching for `duplicated questions search` **will not make your question show up** but it will show the duplicate, this is one of the reasons it's handy to keep duplicates rather than deleting them.

Comment: So if someone looked for "duplicated questions search", they should be linked to my question because that question was closed as a dupe of mine, no? With the "Can we have less duplicated questions show up in the search?" showing up lower in the results set because it was closed as a dupe (with answer pointing to mine). I didn't mean to suggest that they be removed from searches all together, more that the accepted answer gets higher priority. I'm sure that a evaluating whether an item should be included in a search result could additionally analyze it's "closed as dupe" branches.

Comment: Your first question is a meta question on it's own. But please note that duplicates must remain accessible, as accessing the original just takes another click it shouldn't be much of a problem. Now, for the other part of your comment: As your question didn't show up in the search I gave as an example, there is no point in making the duplicate (which does show up in the first place) to show at a lower place.